# Interview Question - Which numbers shows up most times in a list of intervals

Tags: algorithm, intervals

I only heard of this question, so I don't know the exact limits. You are given a list of positive integers. Each two consecutive values form a closed interval. Find the number that appears in most intervals. If two values appear the same amount of times, select the smallest one.

Example: `[4, 1, 6, 5]` results in `[1, 4], [1, 6], [5, 6]` with `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` each showing up twice. The correct answer would be 1 since it's the smallest.

I unfortunately have no idea how this can be done without going for an O(n^2) approach. The only optimisation I could think of was merging consecutive descending or ascending intervals, but this doesn't really work since `[4, 3, 2]` would count 3 twice.

Edit: Someone commented (but then deleted) a solution with this link http://www.zrzahid.com/maximum-number-of-overlapping-intervals/. I find this one the most elegant, even though it doesn't take into account the fact that some elements in my input would be both the beginning and end of some intervals.

Comment: I could imagine O(n^2) algorithm where `n` - number of intervals. Does `n` in the question have the same meaning?

Comment: @Renat I was thinking more of a O(n*m), where n is the number of intervals and m would be a max repeating distance, but I went with them being equal so n^2 :D

Comment: There are many O(nlogn) algorithms solving this question as shown by the various answers. To do better, if it is possible, an algorithm would have to take advantage of the specificity of this problem: that each interval in the list starts at the end point of the previous interval, and ends at the start point of the next interval.

Answer (score 1):

Sort intervals based on their starting value. Then run a swipe line from left (the global smallest value) to the right (the global maximum value) value. At each meeting point (start or end of an interval) count the number of intersection  with the swipe line (in `O(log(n))`). Time complexity of this algorithm would be `O(n log(n))` (`n` is the number of intervals).

Answer (score 1):

The major observation is that the result will be one of the numbers in the input (proof left to the reader as simple exercise, yada yada).

My solution will be inspired by @Prune's solution. The important step is mapping the input numbers to their order within all different numbers in the input.

I will work with C++ std. We can first load all the numbers into a set. We can then create map from that, which maps a number to its order within all numbers.

```
int solve(input) {
  set<int> vals;
  for (int n : input) {
    vals.insert(n);
  }
  map<int, int> numberOrder;
  int order = 0;
  for (int n : vals) {  // values in a set are ordered
    numberOrder[n] = order++;
  }
```

We then create process array (similar to @Prune's solution).

```
  int process[map.size() + 1];  // adding past-the-end element
  int curr = input[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
    last = curr;
    curr = input[i];
    process[numberOrder[min(last, curr)]]++;
    process[numberOrder[max(last, curr)] + 1]--;
  }
  int appear = 0;
  int maxAppear = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < process.size(); ++i) {
    appear += process[i];
    if (appear > maxAppear) {
      maxAppear = appear;
      maxOrder = i;
    }
  }
```

Last, we need to find our found value in the map.

```
  for (pair<int, int> a : numberOrder) {
    if (a.second == maxOrder) {
      return a.first;
    }
  }
}
```

This solution has O(n * log(n)) time complexity and O(n) space complexity, which is independent on maximum input number size (unlike other solutions).

Comment: I may not have understood your solution, but it provides the wrong output most of the time. `1 2 3` works fine, `9 8 3` fails, `4 1 5 2` fails.

Answer (score 0):

If the maximum number in the range array is less than the maximum size limit of an array, my solution will work with complexity o(n).

1- I created a new array to process ranges and use it to find the
    numbers that appears most in all intervals. For simplicity let's use
    your example. the input = [1, 4], [1, 6], [5, 6]. let's call the new
    array  process and give it length 6 and it is initialized with 0s
    process = [0,0,0,0,0,0].

2-Then loop through all the intervals and mark the start with (+1) and
    the cell immediately after my range end with (-1)

- for range [1,4] process = [1,0,0,0,-1,0]
- for range [1,6] process = [2,0,0,0,-1,0]
- for range [5,6] process = [2,0,0,0,0,0]

3- The p rocess array will work as accumulative array. initialize a
        variable let's call it appear = process[0] which will be equal to 2
        in our case. Go through process and keep accumulating what can you
        notice? elements 1,2,3,4,5,6 will have appear =2 because each of
        them appeared twice in the given ranges .

4- Maximize while you loop through process array you will find the
    solution

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = new int[] { 4, 1, 6, 5 };
    System.out.println(solve(arr));


}

public static int solve(int[] range) {
    // I assume that the max number is Integer.MAX_VALUE

    int size = (int) 1e8;
    int[] process = new int[size];

    // fill process array
    for (int i = 0; i < range.length - 1; ++i) {
        int start = Math.min(range[i], range[i + 1]);
        int end = Math.max(range[i], range[i + 1]);

        process[start]++;
        if (end + 1 < size)
            process[end + 1]--;
    }
    // Find the number that appears in most intervals (smallest one)
    int appear = process[0];
    int max = appear;
    int solu = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        appear += process[i];

        if (appear > max){
            solu = i;
            max = appear;
        }

    }
    return solu;
}
```

}

Comment: So you have an array of 100 million elements (and then iterate over it with 100 million iterations) even though you are processing an array of 4 elements? That sounds like a terrible idea. While it is technically O(n), it is very slow. Even if you bounded it by minimal and maximal input value, the problem would not get solved. You don't want to iterate 100 million of times when someone inputs just two numbers like {0, 100000000}.

Comment: @Renat "list of positive integers"

Comment: @Renat I tried with the list you mentioned my algorithm will produce 2 as an answer. process array =[2,1,0,0,-1,-1] and you are accumulating. so when you reach index 2 your accumulation will be 3 which is the maximum

Comment: Dang. Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Think of these as parentheses: `(` to start and interval, `)` to end.  Now check the bounds for each pair [a, b], and tally interval start/end markers for each position: the lower number gets an interval start to the left; the larger number gets a close interval to the right.  For the given input:

```
Process [4, 1]
result: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1]
Process [1, 6]
result: [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1]
Process [6, 5]
result: [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, -2]
```

Now, merely make a cumulative sum of this list; the position of the largest value is your desired answer.

```
result: [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1, -2]
cumsum: [0, 2, 2, 2, 2,  1, 2,  0]
```

Note that the final sum *must* be 0, and can never be negative.  The largest value is 2, which appears first at position 1.  Thus, 1 is the lowest integer that appears the maximum (2) quantity.

No that's one pass on the input, and one pass on the range of numbers.  Note that with a simple table of values, you can save storage.  The processing table would look something like:

```
[(1,  2)
 (4, -1)
 (5,  1)
 (6, -2)]
```

If you have input with intervals both starting and stopping at a number, then you need to handle the starts first.  For instance, [4, 3, 2] would look like

```
[(2,  1)
 (3,  1)
 (3, -1)
 (4, -1)]
```

**NOTE**: maintaining a sorted insert list is **O(n^2)** time on the size of the input; sorting the list afterward is **O(n log n)**.  Either is **O(n)** space.

My first suggestion, indexing on the number itself, is **O(n)** time, but **O(r)** space on the *range* of input values.
    [

Comment: This solution complexity is not dependent on amount of numbers, but on size of biggest number. If you have input {50000, 1000000, 1}, you are suddenly working with list of size 1000000 which you are about to sort, although you had just mere 3 input numbers. That definitely doesn't sound right. And, there is no set limit for the size of numbers, they could as well be `long long`. I don't know about you, but I don't have space for 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 numbers in my RAM.

Comment: I don't think people who downvoted this answer read it carefully enough. (@BoltKey I don't know if you did or not, but your comment is wrong. Prune presented more than one way to store data while processing the input, including one like yours. Please read more carefully.)

Comment: @BoltKey: I'm not sure why you're "leaning" on a point I included in my answer.  I present two methods and compare complexities; you appear to contest the answer without reference to that comparison.